# Groove dimension of 4216 or 88393?

Tags: piece-information, size

What is the dimension of the groove of LEGO part #4216 or #88393?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/library/official/parts/4216.dat), the slot is 8 LDU wide (1 plate, 3.2mm) and 5 LDU deep (quarter module or stud, 2.0mm). Here's the relevant quads from the LDraw file for reference:

[image: width]

[image: depth]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I guess you mean 3.2 mm wide and 2.0 mm deep? I don't know LDraw. But I guess these are the correct dimensions.

Comment: That's correct. I misplaced my decimal converting to millimeters originally, but the correct dimensions are ~3.2mm wide and ~2.0mm deep.